# Create or override Rails Active Record macros

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macros, timestamp, rails-activerecord

In a Rails app, Active Record creates `created_at` and `updated_at` columns thank to macros, (it seems to be also called "magic columns").

See [Active Record Migrations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migration-overview)

I have some questions about that mecanism:

- Is it possible to override that to get a third column (e.g. `deleted_at`) ?
- Is it possible to create a new macro `t.publishing` that will create `publish_up` and `publish_down` columns, for example?
- And where to code that?

Obviously, I know I can add those columns manually, but I wonder how to achieve it with macros.

Working on Rails 4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ActiveRecord::ConnectionsAdapters::TableDefinition::Table` class is responsible for all the high-level migrations stuff like `column`, `index`, `index_exists?` and so on. It has `timestamps` method which adds `created_at` and `updated_at` columns for you:

```
  # Adds timestamps (+created_at+ and +updated_at+) columns to the table. 
  # See SchemaStatements#add_timestamps
  # t.timestamps
  def timestamps
    @base.add_timestamps(@table_name)
  end
```

Basically, you could monkeypatch it in this way (somewhere in your initializers):

```
class ActiveRecord::ConnectionsAdapters::TableDefinition::Table
  def timestamps
    @base.add_timestamps(@table_name)
    @base.add_column(@table_name, :deleted_at, :datetime)
  end
end
```

The same applies to creating a new macro:

```
class ActiveRecord::ConnectionsAdapters::TableDefinition::Table
  def publishing
    @base.add_column(@table_name, :publish_up, :datetime)
    @base.add_column(@table_name, :publish_down, :datetime)
  end
end
```

After that, you should be able to do these things:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.timestamps
      t.publishing
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

Check out the class [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/75a2e4a8dff8c01dad913048d3676b993a8e23a2/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb) at github for more insights.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got it working by monkeypatching the TableDefinition class https://gist.github.com/jocelynduc/3a34478ed3e7da3a0dcb