# Why does ActiveRecord make an unwanted foreign key constraint on my new table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, rails-migrations

I am trying to make a polymorphic model in ActiveRecord. It should have a one-to-one relationship with another object of any type. I am following the [Understanding Polymorphic Associations in Rails](https://launchschool.com/blog/understanding-polymorphic-associations-in-rails) blog post from LaunchSchool.

My migration:

```
# Expresses an explanation for an action or event
class CreateReasons < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :reasons do |t|
      t.string :description
      t.integer :event_id
      t.string :event_type

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Note that I am *not* calling `add_foreign_key`.

My model class:

```
# Expresses an explanation for an action or event
class Reason < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event, polymorphic: true
end
```

The same error occurs if I remove this line.

When I run `rake db:migrate` (with or without `bundle exec`), I get an error, I think because of a foreign key constraint:

```
D, [2016-04-05T22:40:41.389615 #45464] DEBUG -- :    (9.7ms)  CREATE TABLE "reasons" ("id" serial primary key, "description" character varying(255), "event_id" integer, "event_type" character varying(255), "created_at" timestamp, "updated_at" timestamp, CONSTRAINT fk_reasons_event_id FOREIGN KEY ("event_id") REFERENCES "events" ("id"))
E, [2016-04-05T22:40:41.390720 #45464] ERROR -- : PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "events" does not exist
: CREATE TABLE "reasons" ("id" serial primary key, "description" character varying(255), "event_id" integer, "event_type" character varying(255), "created_at" timestamp, "updated_at" timestamp, CONSTRAINT fk_reasons_event_id FOREIGN KEY ("event_id") REFERENCES "events" ("id"))
D, [2016-04-05T22:40:41.391245 #45464] DEBUG -- :    (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
```

I don't know where this constraint came from, and I don't think I want it because this relationship should be polymorphic (the `event` relationship can be any type). Why is it there? What did I do wrong?

Comment: FYI: I did a bunch of digging and am pretty convinced that there is no magic implicit/automatic adding of fk constraints. I thought there may have been a naming convention thing going on, but I haven't found anything like that. See https://robots.thoughtbot.com/referential-integrity-with-foreign-keys which links to https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/15606 -- nothing about implicit fk's. Also the [rails 5 activerecord changelog](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.0.0.beta1/activerecord/CHANGELOG.md) which also has nothing about implicit fk's. So I'm pretty sure that's not it.

Comment: @alexanderbird +1. it seems AR is infering event_id to be a reference and magically adding the foreign key constraint. I wonder if its one of convention things that blowing up. (event being singular)

Comment: It does look like it's inferring it, but from the documentation I couldn't see any indication that that's how it does it. If there was any such magic before 4.2, there would be no need for the [foreigner gem](https://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner), and then later the [pull request to provide this natively](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/15606). I didn't read all the change logs since then, but at least the 5.0.0 change log had nothing about adding such magic, nor did my googling show anything. Also I tried it out with mysql2 on rails 4.2.5 and there was no fk added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your migration seems ok and I can hardly imagine this kind of behaviour provided by `ActiveRecord` itself. More than that, foreign key automatically generated by `Rails` would probably be named `index_reasons_on_event_id`, but not `fk_reasons_event_id`.

In my opinion, there is something going behind the scenes here, like patching `ActiveRecord::ConnectionsAdapters`, as was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24201039/create-or-override-rails-active-record-macros/24201862#24201862).

I would suggest to check initializer files for some nasty monkeypatching and probably your Gemfile for something alike `automatic_foreign_key` or `schema_plus`, which can infer foreign keys from column names and relations automatically.

Comment: Thanks! `schema_plus` (or, more specifically, `schema_auto_foreign_keys` which it includes) was the culprit in my case. I added `foreign_key: false` to my migration and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Rails guide documents a different way of writing migration. [SEE](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

```
class CreateReasons < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :reasons do |t|
      t.string :description
      t.references :event, polymorphic: true, index: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I have used the way mentioned in your question for earlier version of rails.